# How to synchronize files over FTP with Eclipse RSE?

Tags: eclipse, ftp

I installed Helios, which has the latest version of the RSE package, and I could copy files from the remote server just fine, but I don't seem to be able to use the "Review/Synchronize" option. I select the folder on the remote directory, specify the "Into folder" of the local directory, hit Finish, and nothing ever gets synced. Thoughts?

Comment: +1 for asking a good question!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have an explication in this tutorial :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=110113

I copy-paste the content:

**How to install:**

1. Click `Help > Software Updates`
2. Click `Add Site` button, then `Add Site` dialog pops up.

   In the dialog, input `http://eclipse-incub.sourceforge.net/updates-soc/rse-sync/` into the `Location` field and press `OK`.
3. Check the box of the site you just created and click `Install` button.

**How to run Preparation:**

It's necessary to create connection with remote host in RSE, if you have not had ssh connection in RSE yet.

1. `Window > Open Perspective > Remote System Explorer`
2. In Remote Systems view, click the leftmost icon in the tool bar and `New Connection` dialog pops up.
3. In the dialog, select the `SSH Only` as a connection type and click `Next`.
4. Fill the blanks to meet your environment and `Finish`. Now ssh connection is created.

**Initial synchronize:**

For initial synchronize, you can "import" from remote resource to local project or "export" from local project to remote folder.

<<Import:>>

1. Right-click the arbitrary folder you want to import from in RSE and click `Import To Project...(Sync)` on the pop-up menu.
2. The `Import Wizard` pops up. The remote folder is already selected but you can change by clicking top-right `Browse` button.
3. You need to select the destination local project to import. Input the destination project name in the `Into folder` field or select with the `Browse` button.
   The destination project must exist in local side.
4. Check operations.

   `Review/Synchronize`: Manual import. You can import resources you want by yourself in Team Synchronize Perspective.

   `Overwrite existing resources without warning`: Currently this option is ignored. Always no warning.

   `Save the settings..`: Save the setting for re-synchronization. If check this box, you need to decide where setting file is saved in the local workspace.

   *Re-synchronization cannot run without this setting file. The extension of the setting file is `rimpfd`.*
5. Click Finish.

   Unless you check the box of `Review/Synchronize`, the import operation done automatically.

   Otherwise, you are asked to switch perspective to Team Synchronize.

   5-a. In Team Synchronize view, you can see the marked resources you selected. You can "Get" to import resources.

<<Export:>>

1. Right-click the arbitrary folder you want to export to in RSE and click `Export From Project...(Sync)` on the pop-up menu.
2. The `Export Wizard` pops up. The remote folder is already selected but you can change by clicking `Browse` button.
3. You need to select the resources to export.
4. Check operations.

   `Review/Synchronize`: Manual export. You can export resources you want by yourself in Team Synchronize Perspective.

   `Overwrite existing resources without warning`: Currently this option is ignored. Always no warning.

   `Save the settings..`: Save the setting for re-synchronization. If check this box, you need to decide where setting file is saved in the local workspace.

   *Re-synchronization cannot run without this setting file.The extension of the setting file is `rexpfd`*
5. Click Finish.

   Unless you check the box of `Review/Synchronize`, the export operation done automatically.

   Otherwise, you are asked to switch perspective to Team Synchronize.

   5-a. In Team Synchronize view, you can see the marked resources you selected. You can "Put" to export resources.

**Re-Synchronize:**

1. Right-click the setting file which has extension of `rimpfd` or `rexpfd` in Package Explorer.

   1-a: If you select `rimpfd`, click the `Import from Remote File System (Sync)`

   1-b: If you select `rexpfd`, click the `Export to Remote File System (Sync)`
2. Then you are asked to switch perspective to Team Synchronize as the same to manually initial synchronization.
3. In the Team Synchronize view, you can "Get" the remote change or "Put" the local change.

Comment: If you find "Put" or "Get" are missing from the Team Synchronisation dialog, try clearing the target and performing a complete resynchronisation. I found that this then correctly showed the dialog options, when previously no "Put" or "Get" options were available.

Comment: did not work for me :-( **`Unhandled event loop exception` ... `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject`** at `org.eclipse.rse.internal.synchronize.RSESyncUtils.getSynchronizeResources(RSESyncUtils.java:100)`, **`eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400` (Neon 3)**, `java.version=1.8.0_121`, **`Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime 3.7.2.201610260947 org.eclipse.rse.feature.group Eclipse TM Project´** ... I guess it stopped working with newer Eclipse versions :-(

Answer (score 8):

Just for the record.

It is no longer necessary to install any additional plugins (the linked rse-sync) since this functionality has been long implemented into the core of RSE.

The instructions posted are still valid, only the Menu entries have been renamed from **Import from Remote File System (Sync)** and **Export to Remote File System (Sync)** to **Export to Project...** and **Import from Project...**

Cheers

Comment: Do the *pfd files still work? I export them but when I click on them I get no context entry for "Export to Remote File System (Sync)"

Answer (score 2):

in indigo it fails if using jre7 you need jre6.

I found best way was to modify eclispe.ini

just add

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe
```

or where ever the jre6 is !

Answer (score 0):

At Re-Synchronization phase I didnt get the 2nd, and 3rd step. So I dont know where can I see this GET, and PUT method, but only doing the 1st step I could update to remote. I could see FTP commands in console durring sync. By the way I used this site to get the update site for RSE:
http://download.eclipse.org/tm/downloads/index.php
Then 2 packages needs to be downloaded: RSE End-User Runtime, and RSE FTP service