# GNATbench Ada in eclipse using Remote System Explorer

Tags: eclipse, ada, gnat, eclipse-rse

I use GNATbench Ada plugin for eclipse to make eclipse Ada aware on Windows. This works well for local files, but my main development is on a remote Unix box. I successfully use the Remote System Explorer plugin for eclipse to remotely edit C files on the Unix box from Windows, but cannot get the same to work for Ada.

It seems that the GNATbench plugin does not work correctly with the Remote System Explorer (RSE) plugin. Possibly a bug in GNATbench that is directly addressing files with a full path rather than addressing them from a eclipse project point of view.

Has anybody tried this?

Comment: VNC remotely? VirtualBox locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to synchronize files over FTP with Eclipse RSE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947444/how-to-synchronize-files-over-ftp-with-eclipse-rse)